# Cortex M3 - Calling a SVC inside a C function, and returning to thread mode

Tags: gcc, cortex-m, armv7

I am writing System Calls, as recommended by Joseph Yiu (M3 Guide), by taking the arguments from the stack. The Assembly SVC Handler is like:

```
     SVC_Handler:
     MOV R0, #0
     MSR CONTROL, R0
     CMP LR, #0xFFFFFFFD
     BEQ KernelEntry
     B   KernelExit

    KernelEntry: 
    <save current user stack>
    B svchandler_main

    KernelExit:
    <code to restore the very same saved user stack saved before>
    MOV LR, #0xFFFFFFFFD
    BX      LR
```

Well, so the **svchandler_main** is C function that recovers the immediates (arguments of the the system call) creates the kernel stack and branches to 0xFFFFFFFF9 (MSP privileged). The system call itself is made like:

```
#define svc(code) asm volatile ("svc %[immediate]"::[immediate] "I" (code))
void SysCall_MyCall(int32_t args)
{
  svc(CallBack_Number);
}
```

That said, the callback function, running in handler mode:

```
void SysCallBack(void* args)
{
  /* <my c routine>*/
  asm volatile("svc #0"); //to exit the kernel mode
}
```

The last SV Call is performed so that the SVC_Handler in assembly will identify it is coming from handler mode (MSP privileged) and will exit the kernel - kind of a cooperative scheduling on the kernel. The problem is the context is saved with PSP pointing inside SysCall_MyCall, and it returns to there, and never exits. If I use inline functions, I will lose the handy **svchandler_main**. Any ideas? I didnt write the **svchandler_main** here because it is a classic code found on ARM application notes. Thanks.

Edit, to clarify: I am not branching to the callback function INSIDE SVC Handler. It creates the callback stack, change the LR to 0xFFFFFFF9 and execute a BX LR, exiting the the interruption, and going to the indicated MSP. To exit kernel another SVC is called, and user thread resumed.

Comment: Can I just clarify your intention, please?  Are you just trying to use SVC callbacks in the 'standard' way (that is, to provide a way to have callbacks run with privilege, and then for thread mode to be resumed on return)?  If not, what is your use-case?  I'll add an answer once I understand more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: @cooperised yes, exactly that. when the callback is executed on handler mode, it calls another svc to switch to thread mode again. but since i called the svc inside SysCall_MyCall, it resumes the user thread there, and dont go further, that is, performs the same system call again.

Comment: @cooperised i got away with that by defining a macro function for system call, and pushing the arguments to the stack explicitly with inline ASM, but i dont really like that.

Comment: Why does the callback need to call an SVC to switch to thread mode?  Why can't it just switch back to thread mode at the end?  Invoking the SVC handler from within the SVC handler is, anyway, impossible...

Comment: @cooperised hi, i am not calling a svc inside another. the svc creates the kernel stack for that thread. the exit mechanism then pops out the stackframe to the core register and executes it outside the handler, so i dont have to manage nested interrupts, when systick fires... but i totally get your point.

Comment: No - when the SVC handler returns, thread mode is restored and execution continues from the line below the SVC instruction.  I think you're misunderstanding how exception entry and return works.  The write to the `CONTROL` register in your SVC handler reinforces that view.  I will happily write an answer but I want it to be as helpful as possible given what you want to achieve - can you describe your actual requirements?

Comment: about the writing to the control register, is because as I was in thread mode (0x3), if I get interrupted while on thread mode, and switch to MSP mode without changing the privilege bit, it will return as a 0b01, MSP non-privileged. thats the reason. my requirements are as simple as creating system calls.

Comment: Not so.  I'll expand on this in my answer.

Comment: well, im pretty sure its hapenning in front of my eyes (i see on the de debugger) and that i read that afterwards changing to unprivileged mode the only way to turn back is writing it again to 0. it does not mean though that inside exceptions you are not privileged. but by not following the normal flow (like changing LR) its the only way as I could get it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209882/discussion-between-cleveraintwise-and-cooperised).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you misunderstand how exception entry and return works on the Cortex-M.  When you issue an `SVC` instruction from thread mode, the CPU transitions to handler mode just as for any other exception.

Handler mode is always privileged, and always uses the main stack (MSP).  Thread mode can be either privileged or unprivileged depending on the `nPRIV` bit (bit 0) in the `CONTROL` register, and may be configured to use the process stack (PSP) by setting the `SPSEL` bit (bit 1) in the `CONTROL` register from thread mode.

On entry to handler mode, `r0-r3`, `r12`, `lr`, `pc` and `xPSR` are pushed to the active stack (PSP or MSP, depending on which is in use) and an exception return value is loaded into `lr`.  The stack is switched to MSP.  At the end of the handler, a `BX lr` instruction (or equivalent) causes this value to be used as a branch target, which automatically causes a restoration of the previous mode and stack, and pops `r0-r3`, `r12`, `lr`, `pc` and `xPSR`.  The pop of `pc` restores execution from the place where the interrupt occurred.

The important thing about this mechanism is that it is 100% compatible with the ARM ABI.  In other words, it is possible to write an ordinary function and use it as an exception handler, just by placing the address of the function in the appropriate place in the interrupt vector table.  That's because the return at the end of a function is actioned by `BX lr` or equivalent, which is exactly the same instruction that triggers a return from handler mode.

So to write an SVC handler that makes use of callbacks, it is necessary to:

- Work out which stack was in use when the SVC instruction was issued
- Dig out the stacked `pc` to find the address of the SVC instruction itself, and extract the 8-bit constant from within the SVC instruction
- Use the constant to work out which callback to invoke
- Branch to (*not* call) the appropriate callback

The callback can be a perfectly ordinary function.  When it returns, it will trigger the return from handler mode because the appropriate exception return code will still be in `lr`.

A handler that does all of this is presented in the M3 Guide, chapter 10.

If it is required that the callback receives arguments, this is a bit more complex but I can expand my answer if you'd like.  Generally handler callbacks execute in handler mode (that's pretty much the point of SVC).  If for some reason you need the callback to be executed without privilege, that's more complex still; there is an example in Chapter 23 of the M3 guide, though.  You refer in the comments to not wanting to "manage nested interrupts" but really nested interrupts just manage themselves.